# comparing lists in a list

Tags: python-3.x, list

Hi I was trying to do an exercise in which you get n lines of two numbers separated by space as inputs(for example a product info). The first number is price of the product and the second one is value of it and the goal is to find if there is any product which price is lower and it's value is higher for example :

```
2
4 5
3 6
```

This condition should print(yes), but this for example:

```
3
7 9
4 6
3 2
```

should print(no)

I came up with this :

```
n = int(input())
a = []
for x in range(n):
    a.append(input().split( ))
for m in range(n):
    a[m][0] = int(a[m][0])
    a[m][1] = int(a[m][1])
b = max(a)
for z in range(n):
    a[z].reverse()
c = max(a)
c.reverse()
if c == b:
    print('no')
else:
    print('yes')
```

But it's not working for this `[[1,3],[3,1]]` and same ones and it's obvious why but anyway can anyone help me somehow find a solution ?

Comment: Is the desired output for ```[[1,3],[3,1]]``` no?

Comment: And also pls specify ur requirement properly. Should it print yes if any of the products have a lower price or should it print yes if all products have a lower price?

Comment: By "price is lower" did you mean "price is the lowest"? Otherwise the question doesn't make sense.

Comment: [1,3][3,1] should print yes cause 1 in the first list is smaller than 3 in the second list and 3 in the first list is bigger than 1 in the second list

Comment: price  doesn't have to be the lowest , let's put it in this way we have a list of lists and we want to compare these lists in a way to find at least two lists in which the first char of one list is smaller than the other and at the same time the second char of the first list is bigger than the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hi again as I did not receive any answer on this topic so I decide to post an answer when I find one and here it is:

```
a = [input().split( ) for i in range(int(input()))]
b = []
for m in range(len(a)):
    a[m][0] = int(a[m][0])
    a[m][1] = int(a[m][1])

for x in range(len(a)):    
    for z in range(x+1,len(a.copy())):    
        if (a[x][0] < a[z][0] and a[x][1] > a[z][1]) or (a[x][0] > a[z][0] and a[x][1] < a[z][1]):
            b.append([1])
        elif (a[x][0] > a[z][0] and a[x][1] > a[z][1]) or (a[x][0] < a[z][0] and a[x][1] < a[z][1]):
            b.append([2])

if [1] in b:
    print('yes')
else:
    print('no')
```

hope you enjoy !